# Не отображается код версии в отзывах в Google Play Developer Console

Tags: android, google-play

В последнее время стали появляться отзывы к приложению, в которых не отображается код версии и номер версии. На их месте просто прочерк. Отзывы в основном негативные, некоторые пишут про вылеты, но в пункте "Сбои и ANR" - ничего нет.
Заметил свое приложение на каких-то странных сайтах, они могут его как-то модифицировать? Программа простая и вылетать там по сути нечему. Как помочь людям с вылетами? Просить их перекачать приложение с Маркета?

Comment: Поставьте себе Crashlytics Fabric, что бы отслеживать когда и из-за чего падает приложение.

Answer (score 1):

Ваше приложение никто не может модифицировать, кроме вас (ну или того у кого есть доступ к консоли разработчика). Попробуйте пообщаться с пользователями и выяснить проблему вылетов, плюс протестировать на других устройствах. После теста - обновляйте версию приложения, обновление само отобразится у пользователей, они обновят приложение.